# Show that for any two positive real numbers $a, b: \frac a{a + 2b} + \frac b{b + 2a} ≥ \frac12$

Tags: inequality

**Question**:

> Show that for any two positive real numbers $a, b: \frac a{a + 2b} + \frac b{b + 2a} ≥ \frac12$.

So for this question, I began by expanding all terms and moving them all to one side. However, I do not know how to definitively say that the statement is proved.

This is my "work" so far:

$a, b: \frac a{a + 2b} + \frac b{b + 2a} ≥ \frac12$

$\frac {2a(b + 2a) + 2b(a + 2b) - 1(b + 2a)(a + 2b)}{2(a + 2b)(b+2a)} ≥ 0$

$\frac {4ab + 4a^2 + 4b^2 - 2b^2 - 5ab - 2a^2}{4b^2 + 10ab + 4a^2} ≥ 0$

$\frac {2a^2 - ab + 2b^2}{4b^2 + 10ab + 4a^2} ≥ 0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What did you get when expanding and moving all?

Comment: You need that $0 \leq (a-b)^2 \implies (a^2 + b^2) \geq 2ab.$

Comment: Edited it to make it more specific

Comment: @JohnOmielan Not the same inequality on your link in AoPS

Comment: Now you have shown your work... the denominator must be >0, so you just need to show that the numerator >0.

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you for noticing & letting me know. I misread the inequality there initially thinking it was the same one. To help avoid any potential confusion, I've deleted my comment with the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it, just use

$$2a^2-ab+2b^2 = 2(a-b)^2+3ab > 0$$

(and the denominator is positive as well).

Comment: Yes, this is probably the answer that at my stage of learning is most appropriate, thank you.

Comment: @Jamie You could accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One of $a$ or $b$ is non zero, or else the question is not well defined.

If $a=b$, then we get left hand side of inequality to be $2/3$, which is $\geq 1/2$ as desired.

So assume $a>b$. Then
$$ \frac{a}{a+2b} + \frac{b}{b + 2a} 
\\ = \frac{a(b+2a)+b(a+2b)}{(a+2b)(b+2a)} 
\\ = \frac{2ab+2a^2+2b^2}{3ab + (2ab+2a^2 + 2b^2)}
\\ = \frac{x}{3ab + x} \mbox{ where } x = 2ab+2a^2 + 2b^2 > 0
\\ = \frac{1}{\frac{3ab}{x} + 1}
$$
So we need to show that
$$\frac{3ab}{x} \leq 1 \iff 3ab \leq x \iff ab \leq 2a^2+2b^2 $$
But the furthest right inequality is obvious  since
$$ ab < a^2 < 2a^2 < 2a^2 + 2b^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

first let's do some cleaning:
$$\frac{a}{a+2b}+\frac{b}{b+2a} = \frac{2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2}{2a^2 + 4ab + 2a^2} = \frac{2(a+b)^2 - 2ab}{2(a+b)^2} = 1-\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2}$$
and we have :
$$A = \frac{a}{a+2b}+\frac{b}{b+2a} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{2b}{a}} + \frac{1}{1+\frac{2a}{b}}$$
let $x = \frac{a}{b} $ then we have :
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{x}} + \frac{1}{1+2x} = \frac{x}{x+2} + \frac{1}{1+2x}$$
therefore:
$$f^\prime(x) = \frac{2}{(x+2)^2} - \frac{2}{(1+2x)^2} = 0 \Rightarrow x^2 + 4x + 4 = 4x^2 + 4x + 1\Rightarrow 3x^2-3 = 0 \Rightarrow x = \pm 1 \Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{2}{3}, -2$$
but since both a and b are positive x = -2 is not an option and therefore we have that with x>0 f(x) is always larger than 2/3 which is a subset of the desired result.$\blacksquare$