# How to solve this simple but complicated looking inequality?

Tags: inequality

Completely stuck on solving this question,

Any hints or ideas? I tried expanding but got nowhere with it, it seems to be more complicated than some $a^2\geq 0$.

Comment: It helps to write the inequality in terms of $z=\frac y  x$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4518777/42969

Comment: I suppose I should point out that the inequality isn't really true for $x=y=0$ as the LHS would be undefined and not meaningful.

Comment: Why not $\frac{x}{x+2y}+\frac{y}{y+2x}\geq \frac{x}{2x+2y}+\frac{y}{2y+2x} = \frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

Take the LCM on the RHS.

$\frac{2(x^2 + y^2 + xy)}{2x^2 + 2y^2 + 5 xy} \geq \frac{1}{2}$

Since we know that x and y are strictly non negative, therefore multiplying by the denominator on both sides does not change the inequality sign.

Note that x and y can't simultaneously be $0$ so we are not using 0 anywhere.

Multiply by $2(2x^2 + 2y^2 + 5 xy)$ on both sides.

$4(x^2 + y^2 + xy) \geq 2x^2 + 2y^2 + 5 xy$

Simplifying, we get

$2x^2 + 2y^2 \geq xy$

From here, we can use AM-GM on the LHS to prove that this is true for all non - negative real numbers.

$\frac{2x^2 + 2y^2}{2} \geq \sqrt(2x^2 \cdot 2y^2) $

$\frac{2x^2 + 2y^2}{2} \geq 2xy$

$2x^2 + 2y^2 \geq 4xy$

Comment: How would you use AGM on the last inequality?

Comment: Well you would consider one part to be $2x^2$ and the other to be $2y^2$. I'll just add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well if $x,y =0$ then the left hand side would be undefined the statement is not true.  But it is true for all $x, y: x\ge 0, y\ge 0$ and not both $x,y=0$.

If $x=0$ or $y=0$ then either $\frac x{x+2y} = \frac xx = 1$ or $\frac y{y+2x} =\frac yy =1$. In which case the LHS is at least $1$.

So we just need to show for the cases when $x\ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$.  But then both $x+2y$ and $y+2x$ are positive and

$\frac x{x+2y} + \frac y{y+2x} \ge \frac 12$ if and only if

$2x(y+2x) + 2y(x+2y) \ge (x+2y)(y+2x)$ if and only if

$4x^2 + 4xy + 4y^2 \ge 2x^2 + 5xy + 2y^2$ if and only if

$2x^2 + 2y^2 \ge xy$.

That's obviously true.

The AM-GM inequality says $x^2 + y^2 \ge 2xy > \frac 12 xy$.

Or...

$(x-y)^2 \ge 0$ and so $x^2 - 4xy + y^2 \ge 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 \ge 4xy \ge \frac 12 xy$ so $2x^2 + 2y^2 \ge xy$.

Or we could assume, wolog, that $x\le y$ in which case $x^2 \le xy \le y^2 < 2x^2 + 2y^2$.

Seems like way overkill in the statement.

If $x=y$ then we but $\frac x{x+2y} + \frac y{2+2x} = \frac 23$.

If we substitute $m =\frac {x+y}2$ and $d= m-x$ then we have $y = m+ d$ and we have

$\frac x{x+2y} + \frac y{y+2x} =$

$\frac {m-d}{3m+2d} + \frac {m+d}{3m - 2d}=$

$\frac {(m-d)(3m-2d) + (m+d)(3m+2d)}{(3m+2d)(3m -2d)} =$

$\frac {6m^2+4d^2}{9m^2 - 4d^2} \ge$

$\frac {6m^2}{9m^2} = \frac 23$.

That's a stronger statement:

$\frac x{x+2y} + \frac y{y+2x} \ge \frac 23$.

Comment: Saying that when $x,y =0$ then LHS would be infinite is kind of a loose way of saying that the expression would be undefined.

Comment: @Hersch, yeah but the OP said $LHS \ge RHS$ for all non-negative real $x,y$.  That would mean the statement applies to $x=y=0$.  I wasn't sure if I should say it is *false* for $x=y=0$ as the left hand side is undefined when it can be views as "blowing up" *is* certainly bigger than $\frac 12$.   So I compromised and said "it is sort of true" implying also it's not completely true.... I guess I was cowardly and trying to avoid the entire "what does $\infty$ mean" and "why can't we say $\frac 10 = \infty$" and "isn't $\infty > \frac 12$" discussions for the umpteenth time.

Comment: ... Hmm just realized the LHS would be $\frac 00 + \frac 00$ and not $\frac 10 + \frac 10$.  That is "more undefined" and "more sketchy".  If we "cancel out" terms and wave our hand wildly enough to take flight we can say $\frac 0{0+2\cdot 0} + \frac 0{0 + 2\cdot 0}= \frac {0\times 1}{0\times (1+2)} + \frac {0\times 1}{0\times(1+2)}=\frac 1{1+2} + \frac 1{1+2} = \frac 23$.  But that is *SO* wrong it should only be handled with foreceps while wearing a hazmat suit.

Comment: That zero cancelation was brilliantly funny, especially with that analogy lmao. I suppose your initial statement is correct, just framed in a some what misleading way and it would indeed be better to just say that the expression is undefined at $x = y = 0$ rather than saying it is infinity.

Comment: That actually was a mistake on my part.  I thought it'd reduce in essence to $\frac 10$ rather then to $\frac 00$, that is to see I assume as $x$ and $y$ got arbitrarily small the result would get arbitrarily large.  That was, in hindsight, obviously false.  In fact it should have been obvious that $\frac {x}{x+2y} + \frac y{y+2x}\le 2$.  I think I'd better fix it.